# Magento2: create pdf file option in product details page

Tags: product, pdf, file, download, attachment

I need an option to select the chose upload file (pdf) from admin site and that file will visible and have a download option for users On the product details page on frontend.  below is sample images.
[image]

I followed the several tutorials but did not get exactly  what I need.
please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Sebwite's product downloads module, Which is doing exactly same what you're looking for.

https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-Product-Downloads

Comment: If this works for you then wouldn't hurt you to accept answer ;)

Comment: @anonymous- thanks  to your proper solution its helpful for me...

Comment: please check once  this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296304/magento2-create-toggle-button-yes-no-in-admin-product-page

Comment: guys can you please describe stepwise how the code of file module work. I am new in Magento so want to know deep knowledge flow of it