# Magento2: Create toggle button yes/no in admin product page

Tags: product, category, custom-button, toggle

I want to create a toggle button yes/no in the product or category admin side page. also eager to know its description of flow and binding process. I followed many tutorials but don't get the exact solution that I need.
 like the below images. 
[image]

Comment: You can create an attribute Yes/No for toggle button for category and product attribute.

Comment: See this, may be helpful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272941/how-to-hide-fields-with-toggle-checkbox-in-ui-component-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it works, tested:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ToggleAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;

class ToggleProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * Constants block
     */
    const ENTITY_TYPE_ID = 'catalog_product';
    const ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'somecode';

    /**
     * ModuleDataSetupInterface
     *
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * EavSetupFactory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * ToggleProductAttribute constructor.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            self::ENTITY_TYPE_ID,
            self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE,
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'label' => 'Label',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => Boolean::class,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,grouped,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this 
1. You will have to create new product attribute

Admin >> Stores >> Attributes >> Product >> Add Attributes

2. Select "Yes/No" in Catalog Input Type for Store Owner
3. Fill all your information and save that attribute.
4. Got to Admin >> Stores >> Attributes >> Attribute Set and assign that attribute to your attribute set.
5. Clear cache .

After all these steps this attribute will show on your product page

Comment: thanks to all ....  can you guys please have a complete set of   module

Comment: No need to write any code. Please use above steps and it will create it automatically

Comment: DJ Dev@: hello I created a toggle button for the new shipment method but the issue is **button yes/no** function not able to enable/disable module function.
please refer  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296371/magento2-how-to-create-toggle-button-yes-no-in-admin-side?noredirect=1#comment426710_296371

Answer (score 0):

First Create Attribute for Category and then add below code in `category_form.xml`

```
    <field name="your-attribute-code" sortOrder="335" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">your-attribute-label</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

here I created a new payment method and want to change the current dropdown option into toggle yes/no button. please check the below code and images. Packt/Shipme/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers"><group id="shipme" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50"
                                      showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Shipme</label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Name</label>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Title</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0"><label>Enable express</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="express_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable business</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="business_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea"
                   sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
            </field>
            <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select"
                sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect"
                sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
            </field>
        </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

[image]

that above images picture i want to change into toggle yes/no button. like below images.
[image]

Comment: have you created? or do you find an answer